# How can we attain 3 solutions when using Vieta's Substitution?

Tags: complex-numbers, substitution, cubics

Consider $x^3+px=q$. Substituting $x:=w-\frac{p}{3w}$ will reduce it to $w^3-\frac{p^3}{27w^3}-q=0$. Multiplying with $w^3$ will result in $(w^3)^2-qw^3-\frac{1}{27}p^3=0$.  Using the quadratic formula, we get$$w^3=-\frac{q\pm \sqrt{q^2+\frac{4}{27}p^3}}{2}$$

So this would imply that if $q^2<-\frac{4p^3}{27}$, there would be no solution in the real numbers. But shouldn't there always be a realy solution?

Cf: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VietasSubstitution.html

Comment: This is how people discovered complex numbers [See here.](http://fermatslasttheorem.blogspot.com/2006/12/bombelli-and-invention-of-complex.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $q^2<-\frac{4p^3}{27}$, $w^3$ becomes a complex number and there are three distinctive complex values for $w$ once the cubit root is taken on $w^3$.

The solution to the cubic equation $x^3+px+q$ is instead,

$$x=w-\frac{p}{3w}$$

As a result, there are three distinctive roots for $x$ evaluated from the three $w$’s. However, the roots result in real value due to the cancellation of the imaginary parts of $w$ and $ -\frac{p}{3w}$.

Edit: The solutions to $x^3-\lambda x +2=0$, asked in comments.

Three cases:

1) If $\lambda=3$, i.e. $q^2+\frac{4p^3}{27}=0$, there are three real roots, one double and one single.

$$x_1= -2,\>\>\>\>\>x_{2,3}=1$$

2) If $\lambda<3$, there are three mixed roots, one real and two complex. The real root is given by

$$x_1= \left( -1+\sqrt{1-\frac{\lambda^3}{27}} \right)^{1/3}
+ \left( -1-\sqrt{1-\frac{\lambda^3}{27}}\right)^{1/3}$$

3) If $\lambda>3$, there are three distinctive real roots. Normally they are given by their trigonometric forms as follows,

$$x_1=2\sqrt{\frac {\lambda}{3}} \cos\theta$$

$$x_2=2\sqrt{\frac {\lambda}{3}} \cos\left( \theta-\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)$$

$$x_3=2\sqrt{\frac {\lambda}{3}} \cos\left( \theta-\frac{4\pi}{3}\right)$$

where,

$$\theta= \frac13 \cos^{-1}\left( -\frac{3}{\lambda}\sqrt{\frac{3}{\lambda}}\right)$$

Comment: If I were to ask for which $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ the equation $-x^3+\lambda x-2=0$ has three distinct roots, how would I proceed?

Comment: That happesn when and only when its discriminant is greater than $0$. Since the dicriminant is $4\lambda^3-108$, your equation has $3$ distinct roots when and only when $\lambda>3$.

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic - I added the solutions in all cases for $x^2-\lambda x +2=0$ in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $p=-15$ and that $q=-4$. Then $q^2+\frac4{27}p^3=-484<0$. And$$w^3=-\frac{-4\pm\sqrt{-484}}2=2\mp11i.$$But a cube root of $2\mp11i$ is $2\mp i$ and\begin{align}2\mp i-\frac{-15}{3(2\mp i)}&=2\mp i+\frac5{2\mp i}\\&=2\mp i+2\pm i\\&=4.\end{align}

Comment: Thanks. But what if I want to know for which $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ the equation $-x^3+\lambda x-2=0$ has three distinct roots?